# can i use import instead of require everywhere in javascript while using express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have found so many answers related to it but not single of them has satisfied my problem.
so i am using type:"modules" in package.json
my question is can i use

`app.use(express.json()) app.use('/api/auth',()=>{ **import**('/Routes/auth')    })`

because my mongodb server i up and running but when i send the data using schemas which are at  location ('./Routes/auth') i have to suffer with an error that `'E:\Routes\auth' ,'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'` this is happeing becuase of the import statement but i dont know what to write because i have already tried  require but it's always give me an error that it dont know what require is because i am using type="module"

Plzz someone help me

Answer (score 0):

You want to import the function at the top-level of your file, then reference it

```
import auth from ('./Routes/auth')
<other express logic>
app.use("/auth", auth);
```

Note that "auth" references to a router in ./Routes/auth/

so in ./Routes/auth/ you default export a router (that handles login/logout routes, whatever you have).

Scroll down and see an example [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) (though they don't use ES6)

Comment: thankyou brother it was so easy that in shame i have to commit suicide 